# Why does MS Access prompt to enter parameter in update query which already has values?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, error-handling, ms-access-2010

I am making a database where the user can change the name of a company in a table. However , whenever I use the update query, it asks for a parameter which is already supplied. The old company name is in the variable `new_comp` and then the new one is in the `Me.comp1_box.Value`.

Funny enough the query runs excellently whenever I hit ok and enter nothing inside the "Enter Parameter" setting

```vb
Dim record_changer As String
         
record_changer = "UPDATE " & "[" & new_comp & "]" & " SET " & "[" & new_comp & "]" & ".Company_Name =" & """" & Me.comp1_box.Value & """" & ";"
     
MsgBox (record_changer)
             
DoCmd.RunSQL (record_changer)
```

This is the final value of the record_changer.
UPDATE [EREDEON TECHNOLOGIES] SET [EREDEON TECHNOLOGIES].Company_Name="EREDEON TECH";

This is how it is when the code runs.

- [This is the query that it is supposed to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/232LE.png)
- [It gives this prompt meaning it's supposed to run perfectly, meaning there is nothing wrong with the Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AG86R.png)
- [This what pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgFa8.png)

Can anyone please help me out?
I am genuinely lost.The name of the Old Company name is EREDEON TECHNOLOGIES and the new name is EREDEON TECH
But funny enough when I just hit Okay without entering a value into the parameter dialogue box, it actually makes the changes.-_- weird

- [This happens, then I press "OK"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfLFk.png)
- [THEN THIS HAPPENS, Then I hit Okay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kT9Eq.png)
- [This is the table before.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcyKN.png)
- [It updates the table the new value which is EREDEON TECH. When I just hit OK, without typing anything into Parameter Dialogue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNOSh.png)

Comment: [Bobby Tables: A guide to preventing SQL injection](https://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Change `DoCmd.RunSQL` to `CurrentDb().Execute` to suppress the warning messages. But keep in mind the sql injection issue noted above.

Comment: It seems in the screenshot that EREDEON TECHNOLOGIES is a table name. Is that correct?

Comment: @KostasK. yhh. i tried it and it still gave the same results. I honestly have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: @marlan yhh Marlan. there is Sir.

Comment: Is the value of _new_comp_ the table name and the column name? What is the value of _record_changer_ when you execute the statement? Most likely you have an invalid column name.

Comment: hey @NicholasHunter new_comp is the table name and the column name is called Company_Name. I added a picture of the record_changer to it. let me get it for you. I took a screenshot of it. I cannot add it to this comment unfortunately.

Comment: HEY @NicholasHunter here is the final value of the record_changer..
UPDATE [EREDEON TECHNOLOGIES] SET [EREDEON TECHNOLOGIES].Company_Name="EREDEON TECH";

Comment: If new_comp is the table name, the update statement needs to look like this: **record_changer = "UPDATE [new_comp] SET [new_comp].Company_Name = " & Chr(34) & Me.comp1_box.Value & Chr(34) & ";"**

Comment: @NicholasHunter   I tried this just now. It still gives that same thing. The parameter dialogue came again.Is there a way to turn it off completely.

Comment: Turning off warnings won't resolve issue. Use `CurrentDb.Execute` instead of `DoCmd.RunSQL` to not get warnings. Or use `DoCmd.SetWarnings <True/False>` to deactivate/activate warnings. The popup prompt is because Access can't find field name.

Comment: Start with simplifying SQL concatenation: `"UPDATE [" & new_comp & "] SET Company_Name ='" & Me.comp1_box & "';"`. What exactly is new_comp - a textbox? What is combobox RowSource? Is this a BOUND form and BOUND controls?

Comment: the new_comp is a variable to which the value of the combo box is set to. The the rowsource is a query that runs and fills the combobox with all the list of companies from the form Load event.

Comment: but the weird thing is, whenever i ignore the parameter and then I just hit "OKAY" and not even fill in anything, the UPDATE Query runs perfectly and makes changes to the table.

Comment: This might be linked to form properties like: Order By, LinkChildFields, LinkMasterFields if you have subforms, the Company_Name is bound with a ComboBox, also check it's .RowSource... Your query is absolutely GOOD.

Comment: it works fine when I just hit okay on all the parameter dialogue box. If Access couldn't find the fields, how come it works perfectly when I just just ignore the dialogue box and hit OK throughout. I am really lost tbh.

Comment: yhhh. You are right.Maybe I have not made something editable or something. The rowsource of the combBox is a list of values gotten from a another table called Companies_Table. When the form loads, it takes all of the values from there and fills the combo box with each value.

Comment: @jacouh thank you very very much. you should see the full code. lol

Comment: @jacouh 
Also, I tried to use the open recordset() to open the Eredeon technologies Table and then loop through each value in the Company_Name and then change it "EREDEON TECH".

But guess what, it GAVE THE SAME ERROR! lol
rs.Edit
Do Until rs.EOF
      rs!["Company_Name"] = Me.comp1_box.Value
 Loop
rs.Update.

I did this,and it still gave the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, the issue is due to the use of double quotes in VBA which works in Access SQL by itself but not via VBA using `DoCmd.RunSQL`. You could have used single quotes to enclose company name value.

However, avoid concatenating VBA literals to SQL queries with quotes in the first place. Instead, use the industry best practice of parameterization which is available in MS Access using [QueryDefs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/querydefs-collection-dao) in VBA and `PARAMETERS` clause in SQL:

```vb
Dim record_changer As String
Dim qdef As QueryDef

sql = "PARAMETERS new_name_param TEXT; " _
       & "UPDATE [" & new_comp & "] " _
       & "SET Company_Name = new_name_param;"

' SET UP QUERYDEF
Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", sql)

' BIND PARAMS
qdef!new_name_param = Me.comp1_box.Value

' RUN ACTION
qdef.Execute

' RELEASE RESOURCE
Set qdef = Nothing
```

Nonetheless, the need to concatenate table name, `new_comp`, in query is questionable database design. Proper names (EREDEON TECHNOLOGIES, GAME DISCOUNT STORE, SHOPRITE, etc.) should never be names of tables. Avoid maintaining a separate table for *every* company. Instead, normalize data for a **single** table of all companies, then run `UPDATE` with `WHERE` adding a second parameter.

```vb
' PREPARED STATEMENT, NO VARIABLE CONCATENATION
sql = "PARAMETERS new_name_param TEXT, old_name_param TEXT; " _
      & " UPDATE Companies " _
      & " SET Company_Name = new_name_param" _
      & " WHERE Company_Name = old_name_param;"

Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", sql)

qdef!new_name_param = Me.comp1_box.Value
qdef!old_name_param = new_comp

qdef.Execute
```

In fact, since above SQL is now separated from VBA, save the query without VBA punctuation (`&`, `"`, or `_`) as a separate object and call it in QueryDefs by name:

```
Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("mySavedQuery")

qdef!new_name_param = Me.comp1_box.Value
qdef!old_name_param = new_comp

qdef.Execute
```

---

Even better, if your parameters derive from controls on open forms, include them directly in query for a single line VBA call. Below runs the normalized version of single Companies table:

**SQL** *(save as query object, adjust names to actuals)*

```sql
UPDATE Companies
SET Company_Name = Forms!myForm!comp1_box 
WHERE Company_Name = Forms!myForm!new_comp
```

**VBA** *(no need to close action queries)*

```vb
DoCmd.OpenQuery "mySavedQuery"
```

Comment: hey.Thank u.I doubt the query is the problem cause I used this method and it still told me to enter parameters. 
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset(new_comp, dbOpenDynaset)
        If rs1.RecordCount = 1 Then
            rs1.Edit
                rs1![company_name] = Me.comp1_box.Value
            rs1.Update
        ElseIf rs.RecordCount > 1 Then
            MsgBox ("THE RECORDCOUNT IS MORE THAN ONE")
            rs1.Edit
            Do Until rs1.EOF
                rs1![company_name] = Me.comp1_box.Value
                rs1.MoveNext
            Loop
            rs1.Update
        End If

Comment: when I use the OpenRecordset method and use the rs.Edit and choose the fieldname(Company_Name), it still gives the same results. It tells me to enter parameter. Yet whenever I hit OK in the Enter Parameter Dialogue Box without typing anything, the program proceeds and continues to function perfectly.

Comment: Did you try any of the solutions here? Are you still using separate tables for each store?

Comment: yhh I tried all of the solutions here but none of them worked. But I did find a solution though. A man here answered. Apparently it was from a Single quotation mark. I just had to change it from a double quotation mark to a single quotation mark

Comment: I just caught my typo. Method should be [`CreateQueryDef`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-createquerydef-method-dao). Doing so, you avoid *any* quotes around literal values. I know it's a new concept and may seem like more extraneous lines but it is the recommended route. And really think about normalizing for a single store/company table. Queries will be much easier to write and more efficient for database storage.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your SQL string to the following. Note the *single quotes* change around *Me.comp1_box.Value*.

```
record_changer = "UPDATE " & "[" & new_comp & "]" & " SET " & "[" & new_comp & "]" & ".Company_Name ='" & Me.comp1_box.Value & "';"
```

Misused quote marks is the most common cause for the Parameter Value prompt. If that doesn't work, use this article to perform step-by-step trouble shooting on all of the other usual causes, [Why does Access want me to enter a parameter value?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/why-does-access-want-me-to-enter-a-parameter-value-0e71a1dd-e498-49a1-9e2e-356538d226ff#bm1)

You can also reference the following articles:

> MS Docs, [Quotation marks in string expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/criteria-expressions/include-quotation-marks-in-string-expressions)
> Bytes, [(') and (") - Where and When to use them](https://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/575414-quotes-double-quotes-where-when-use-them)

Comment: BRO THAT ACTUALLY WORKKKKKEDDD!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1
YOU ARE A GENIUS! FOR REAL!
I can't believe I stressed this much just because of a QUOTATION MARK!
How did you even know this?

Comment: You're welcome. I knew this by making the same mistake 2 decades ago. LOL. Please mark this question answered, and use the links I provided to educate yourself. Up-votes are much appreciated.

Comment: thank you Sir. I will. However I tried to rename the Table. But it doesn't work.
It raises no errors, neither does it give anything. I just doesn't work.
    DoCmd.Rename Me.comp1_box.Value, acTable, new_comp
    MsgBox ("THE COMPANY HAS SUCCESSFULLY BEEN RENAMED")

where Me.comp1_box.Value is the New Name for the table and then new_comp is the old name for the table. Could you please help me?

Comment: I will try. Post a **new question** in this forum, please, under the Access and VBA tags. Use StackExchange guidelines.to frame a good question, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask